How to Calculate Average Time from First Activity to a Milestone in a User Activity Log Using data.table in R?
I'm working with a dataset of user activity logs and need to calculate the average time it takes for first-time users to reach a specific milestone. Specifically, I want to find the average time it takes for users who start with a "login" to making a "purchase" at least twice. Here’s a more detailed explanation using example data:
library(data.table)
activity_logs <- data.table(
  user_id = c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5),
  timestamp = as.POSIXct(c(
    "2024-01-01 10:00:00", "2024-01-02 11:00:00", "2024-01-03 12:00:00",
    "2024-01-01 09:00:00", "2024-01-04 14:00:00",
    "2024-01-01 08:00:00", "2024-01-03 10:00:00", "2024-01-05 16:00:00",
    "2024-01-02 07:00:00", "2024-01-03 11:00:00",
    "2024-01-02 12:00:00", "2024-01-03 13:00:00"
  )),
  activity = c(
    "login", "purchase", "purchase", "login", "purchase",
    "login", "purchase", "purchase", "login", "purchase", "login", "login"
  )
)

My code so far:
library(data.table)

# Identify first-time logins
first_time_logins <- activity_logs[, .SD[1][activity == "login"], by = user_id]

# Filter users with at least 2 purchases
activity_logs[user_id %in% first_time_logins$user_id][activity == "purchase"][, .N, by = user_ud][N >= 2]

I am uncertain how to take this any further. Is there a somewhat straightforward way to this? thanks.

the average time is infinity as some users never make two purchases

We can use rowid() to identify the second purchase (if exists) to discard one-time-or-less purchasers and calculate the mean time for the rest.
activity_logs[, time := rowid(user_id, activity)]
logs_2time_customers <- activity_logs[, .SD[any(activity == "purchase" & time == 2)], by = user_id]
logs_2time_customers[, difftime(
                         timestamp[activity=="purchase" & time == 2],
                         timestamp[activity=="login"   & time == 1],
                         units = "hours"
                       ), by = user_id
                     ][, sprintf("Average time difference is %.1f hours", mean(V1))]

# [1] "Average time difference is 77.0 hours"


You could try the following steps:

Merge the data containing filtered users with activity logs to find the login timestamp for all such users.
For each of those filtered users, calculate the time difference using the data generated from 1. Here, it's also important to sort the data based on timestamp for each user to correctly determine the timestamp for the second purchase.
Use the output from 2, to find the mean.

Here's how you can do this in R:
# identify first-time logins
first_time_logins <- activity_logs[, .SD[1][activity == "login"], by = user_id]

# filter users with at least 2 purchases
user_purchases <- activity_logs[user_id %in% first_time_logins$user_id][activity == "purchase"][, .N, by = user_id][N >= 2]

# Step 1: merge to get relevant user ids:
relevant_users <- merge(first_time_logins, user_purchases, by = "user_id")
    
# Step 2: sort purchase timestamps and calculate the time to the second purchase
time_to_second_purchase <- relevant_users[, {
  purchase_times <- activity_logs[user_id == .BY$user_id & activity == "purchase"][order(timestamp), timestamp]
  if (length(purchase_times) >= 2) {
    time_diff <- difftime(purchase_times[2], timestamp, units = "mins")
  } else {
    time_diff <- NA
  }
  list(time_to_second_purchase = time_diff)
}, by = user_id]

# Step 3: find mean
average_time <- mean(time_to_second_purchase$time_to_second_purchase, na.rm = TRUE)

